# json foreach array of arrays with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach

```
[
    [
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Code": "232",
            "TicketImage": "0"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Code": "23",
            "TicketImage": "1"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Code": "24",
            "TicketImage": "1"
        }
    ],
    []
]
```

I have this JSon object which I m trying to parse.

`var res = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(obj.Message));`

```
              $.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(tickets, function (i, ticket) {
                      console.log($(this));
                  });
              });
```

When i try this i get zillions of popups with letters. but i want object.

How can i parse this JSON data?

**UPDATE:**

```
           $.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(tickets, function (i, ticket) { 
                      console.log(ticket.Code);
                      console.log(ticket.TicketImage);
                  });
              });
```

**This did it.**

Comment: `$(this)` will give you the object ? < inside the `.each` loop > unless I am missing something else `:)` hope this helps

Comment: `obj.Message` has the JSON data.

Comment: console.log(obj.message) to make sure the data is correct. then console.log(res) to make sure it parsed correctly.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte yes, they are parsed correctly.

Comment: @Tats_innit still zillions of alert, all undefined.

Comment: can you paste those two console.log() in your question? Will be easier to debug if we can see the actual data, as interpreted after your parsing...

Comment: @DarthVader then your `res` object aint right! there you go check your `res` again and see if it gets populated correctly.

Comment: I have added the console log to the question.

Comment: @Tats_innit yes res is populated correctly that s how i got the output in the questionl

Comment: @Tats_innit `$(this)` didnt do it man. if u use `ticket.Property` it worked. thanks anyways man `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful you are overriding the i variable :

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {
                      console.log(this);
                      // as a full string
                      console.log(this.ticketId+' : '+JSON.stringify(this));

                  });
});
```

​Besides this small thing, your loop is correct, you don't need the jquery wrapper on your 'this'. in $.each(array,function(k,v){}) , the k variable is the key to retrieve the current object and v it's value so you could also access it by doing this :

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(res[i], function (j, ticket) {
                      console.log(res[i][j].ticketId+' : '+res[i][j]);
                      // which is the exact same thing as :
                      console.log.(ticket);
                      // and even this:
                      console.(this);

                  });
});
```

The same code using 'this' :

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(this, function (j, ticket) {
                      console.log(this.ticketId+' : '+this);
                  });
});
```

using each value :

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
                  $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {
                      console.log(ticket.ticketId+' : '+ticket);
                  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var res = jQuery.parseJSON(eval(obj.Message));
```

Comment: If `obj.Message` is a valid JSON string then there is absolutely no need to use `evil`